# vue3 and pinia how to display notifications

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I have this store (pinia):

```
actions: {
        async addCompany ( company ) {
            await axios.post('/api/companies.json', company)
                .then( (response) => {
                    this.companies.push(company);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        },
```

And I call it from my component like this:

```
 methods: {
    saveRow(item) {
      this.store.addCompany(this.editedItem)
    },
```

Everything works ok but now I want to notify the user with toast or Swal or whaterver (I'm using quasar) that everithing was ok or if we got an error. Something like this:
Invented code... is what I wanted to achieve:

```
methods: {
    saveRow(item) {
      const result = this.store.addCompany(this.editedItem)
      if ( result == "OK") {
          alert("All good!)
      } else {
         alert ("HORROR!")
      }
    },
```

you know what I meant... but I can not figure out how to do that. Any help or clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your store you can return the promise from `axios` itself:

```js
addCompany ( company ) {
  return axios.post('/api/companies.json', company)
    .then( (response) => {
        this.companies.push(company);
     })
     .catch((error) => {
       console.log(error);
     });
},
```

Then in your component you can simply do a `.then` just like you did in your store:

```js
import {Notify} from "quasar";

saveRow(item) {
      const result = this
         .store
         .addCompany(this.editedItem)
         .then(() => {
            Notify.create("Company has been added")
         })
         .catch(() => {
            Notify.create("There was an error adding company")
         });

},
```

Feel free to visit MDN's docs on [Javascript Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: oh! So obvious now I see it! Thank's!!

Comment: Surely you would need to throw an error in the in the axios catch body? Other wise the error will ever be caught in the catch body of saveRow()?